# How to get the id of the node where I drop the node that I am dragging

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to use the **compound-drag-and-drop extension of cytoscape** to create an event where I need the id of the node where I am dropping the node that I am dragging. Instead the id that I am getting is a "parent" auto generated by the extension. Is there a way to get the id of my node so I can bind both of them when I drop the first one into the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is exactly what the custom event

```
cy.nodes().bind('cdnddrop', function (event, target){
    var grabbedNodeID = event.target._private.data.id;
    var droppedNodeID = target._private.data.id;
});
```

does, so try it out and see if it helps you.